# Turkish Cyprus (north) stamp in Russian visa application

Tags: visas, transit, russia, cyprus

I am applying to the Russia Embassy in the United Kingdom for a tourism visa.  I went through Northern (Turkish) Cyprus twice in March 2016.  The first was to visit the coach company who took me to Nicosia airport to leave the next week.  Upon leaving, the airport staff stamped my passport with the Turkish (Northern) Cyprus stamp.  I then flew to mainland Turkey for a connecting flight.

In the Russian application, what should be used as a country visited in the last 10 years for that: Cyprus, Turkey, another place, or nothing?

I have also transited through Turkey, Poland and Austria, all on separate occasions to the others.  I had land bus, and train connections in Austria and Poland, from which I went by train in to Czechoslovakia.  I exited Turkey and Austria upon getting to their airports.

Should these be mentioned, as all are within the last 10 years?

Comment: Czechoslovakia is two countries actually

Comment: How is it?  There's one name.

Comment: Chezh Republic and Slovakia, they splited years ago

Answer (score 4):

Turkey is the only country to recognise Kuzey Kıbrıs Türk Cumhuriyeti. To Russsia and others officially the entire island is Cyprus, so put `Cyprus`. Russia won't care that you have visited - it is well aware that thousands/millions of people have - (I recommend the place). Don't try and hide your visit and there is no need to fabricate "another place".  Yes, mention where else you have been. It is a **very bad** idea to lie (even by omission) on a visa application.

Comment: I cannot anyway as I holidayed in Cyprus mainland.  However there are several terms in their list which are not countries and are not easily understandable.  The transited countries too do I include them?

Comment: So even for same airport transits only ?  It wouldn't seem fully relavant to include them, as it's obvious it's not really visiting and doesn't require an out of airport permit of any sort.   My list may have about 15 countries in 10 years.

Comment: From Cyprus mainland. The second time was from mainland Cyprus too, and no I found no way to leave by that method.

Comment: I'm as sure as I recall.  It's the overall Cyprus capital airport, which is in north Cyprus.  The rest of Cypruses capital city does not have another airport in it. It was not the locations you quoted.

Comment: What do you mean  fixed wing?  I flew on commercial Turkish Airlines company. Although happily it left at 4.30 am. Had to wait about 5 hours for itself,